# How to use REG ADD with c++

Tags: c++, windows, registry

i want to use the cmd command "`REG ADD`" at windows. Thats my code:

```
system("REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography /v MachineGuid /t REG_SZ /d %random%-%random%-%random%-%random% /f");
```

When I try in console it works but when I use my code I get this error:
**Invalid Key Name**.

I dont know the problem
I hope you can help me.

Comment: This is a rather convoluted way to do this. You can call `RegCreateKeyExA` directly.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, you need to escape the `\` character when used in a string/character literal, eg:

```
system("REG ADD HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography /v MachineGuid /t REG_SZ /d %random%-%random%-%random%-%random% /f");
```

---

That being said, you really should not be using `system()` like this. Use Win32 APIs instead, namely `CoCreateGuid()`, `StringFromGUID2()`, `RegCreateKeyEx()`, and `RegSetValueEx()`, eg:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <objbase.h>

GUID guid;
HRESULT hRes = CoCreateGuid(&guid);
if (FAILED(hRes)) ...

WCHAR szGuid[40];
int len = StringFromGUID2(&guid, szGuid, 40);
if (len == 0) ...

HKEY hKey;
LSTATUS lRes = RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
if (lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS) ...

lRes = RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"MachineGuid", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)szGuid, len*sizeof(WCHAR));
if (lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS) ...

RegCloseKey(hKey);
```